# save UIButton state iOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a UIButton

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {

if (!checked) {
    [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = YES;
} else if (checked) {
    [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = NO;
}

}
```

I want to save the user input, weather the button is checked or not, even after the app closes. Help me with codes anyone? I don't know the codes to use NSUserDefaults for saving BOOL state.

Comment: Use selected property

Comment: You Want to maintain state in table-view

Comment: yes! The state of the UIButton after the app closes inside the table view.

Comment: Then you should preferably update your tableview's datasource to preserve states and save it to disk or `NSUserDefaults` using `NSKeyedArchiver`: http://benreimers.net.au/blog/saving-and-loading-data-nscoding-and-nskeyedarchiver

Answer (score 1):

Use it by below way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool: checked forKey:@"Status"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve it,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL state = [defaults boolForKey:@"Status"];
```

Comment: The first part will help you to save the state (i.e. in your case variable checked) even when app is closed. The second part will help to retrieve that stored variable. You should use it to set initial status of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Set images for both `Normal` and `selected` state of a button as

```
[checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and in `IBAction` set

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {

    if (!checked) {
        [checkBoxButton setSelected:NO];
        checked = YES;
    } else if (checked) {
        [checkBoxButton setSelected:YES];
        checked = NO;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:hasLaunchedOnceKey])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:hasLaunchedOnceKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //Saves the data
}
```

Where I have:

```
static NSString *hasLaunchedOnceKey = @"HasLaunchedOnce";
```

Declared before the @implementation statement.

See [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039) for an extensive tutorial.

**Note: You do not need to declare anything in any sort of plist files afaik. You can simply check for and set these keys and they will be dynamically created if they don't exist. Works that way for me anyways.

Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

My way is too easy .. You don't need to take any other variable. On initialise set your button tag ZERO and after use this.

```
  - (IBAction)checkButton : (id)sender {

      if ([sender tag] == 0) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:1];
      } else   {
         [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:0];
      }
  }
```

Thanks & Cheers .. May be helpfull..

Comment: Have u checked my answer.. :)